# bundle is null after setting into the intent activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bundle

I'm setting intent to traverse between activities. But here the bundle is null after setting intent. Here is my code,

```
NewCourseActivity.java
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mItemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CourseSelected=parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.BESPINNER:
                    String becourse=parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(NewCourseActivity.this,BEViewCourseActivity.class);
                    Bundle data1 = new Bundle();
                    data1.putString("course",becourse);
                    intent.putExtras(data1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break; } }

BEViewCourseActivity.java:
 CourseSelected=findViewById(R.id.courseSelected);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        if(data != null){
            String selectedcourse = data.getString("course");
            CourseSelected.setText(selectedcourse);
        }
        else{
            CourseSelected.setText("Failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from one activity to another:

```
// updated becourse String
String becourse = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(NewCourseActivity.this , BEViewCourseActivity.class);
intent.putExtra ( "course" , becourse  );
startActivity ( intent );
```

Then receive the passed data:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String stringValue = extras.getString("course"); // string must be the same as the passed one
}
```

Comment: but no data pass through the bundle and the bundle extras in the receiving activities carries null value

Comment: Add a log before starting the activity to check the string's value: Log.i( "MyActivity" , becourse );

Comment: What is "becourse" exactly? What is it supposed to return?

Comment: it returns the data in spinner, which inturn traverse to the receiving activity